# Form's submit button not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, forms

I have a form on my website where the submit button is not working.  This is only occurring on IE though.  It works properly on all other browsers.  Do you know what may be the issue?  Here is the embedded HTML that is being used for the form.  Thank you for any help you could give!

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    .textbox {
    background: #F1F1F1 url(http://html-generator.weebly.com/files/theme/input-text-40.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px -7px !important;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 21px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #CCC inset, 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #CCC inset, 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    color:#666;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #CCC;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #CCC;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #CCC;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   color:    #CCC;s
}

.textbox:focus {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-color: #E8C291;
    outline: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #E8C291 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #E8C291 inset;
}


.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #cf866c;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #cf866c;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #cf866c;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #d0451b), color-stop(1, #781400));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #d0451b 5%, #781400 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d0451b 5%, #781400 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #d0451b 5%, #781400 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #d0451b 5%, #781400 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #d0451b 5%, #781400 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d0451b', endColorstr='#781400',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#d0451b;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:8px 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #854629;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #781400), color-stop(1, #d0451b));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #781400 5%, #d0451b 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #781400 5%, #d0451b 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #781400 5%, #d0451b 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #781400 5%, #d0451b 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #781400 5%, #d0451b 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#781400', endColorstr='#d0451b',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#781400;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


</style>     

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="Logon" name="Logon" action=" https://secure1.ufsdata.com/PBI_PBI1961/pbi1961.ashx?WCI=RemoteLogin&RT=075902308&LogonBy=Connect3" method="post" target onsubmit="return subcount();" autocomplete="off">

<input class="textbox"type="text" id="AccessID" name="AccessID" placeholder="Online Banking ID"> 

<button class="myButton">Submit</button>
</form>
<br><br>
<br><br> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript's `onclick` Event.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button to this:

```
<button type="submit" class="myButton">Submit</button>
```